# Loading external JS Module breaks Configurable Swatches / PrototypeJS in Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, swatches, prototype-js

I'm using an outside JS library built with Webpack and Babel. The library is self-contained and only adds a single global variable.

When this library is loaded onto a product page, the hover-over and select functionality of Magento's configurable swatches breaks.

On hover, colors/sizes still dynamically show stock. But when hovering or clicking the swatches, the following error is logged:

```
(Chrome) Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined   prototype.js:936

(Firefox) TypeError: value[method] is undefined   prototype.js:936:7
```

This traces to `skin/frontend/rwd/default/js/configurableswatches/swatches-product.js:676:40` which is the following:

`el.select('span span').invoke('update', Translator.translate(this._E.cartBtn.txt[index]));`

When I try to then add the product to cart, I get messages saying "Please select a size", etc.

Is there a known problem with Prototype and Babel or Webpack that would cause this?

Comment: I am having this same problem 63.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We eventually determined a way to deal with this.

[Here's](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/5518) a thread about this issue in the Babel GitHub. Based on that thread, our solution was to upgrade Magento's bundled PrototypeJS to 1.7.3, which should be a non-breaking patch. We've seen success with this multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, just an additional comment because the system won't let me add a comment.

I am also having a similar we want to use the Amasty Pre Order extension, and when it is enabled it throws the same errors.